# React native Development - mapbox. Facing issue Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, react-native

Am new to React native Development. Trying to create app with mapbox. Facing issue Execution failed for task ':app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets'. > Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Unable to resolve module `./screens/maps/mapbox` from `C:\Users\windows\xxx\app\App.js`: The module `./screens/maps/mapbox` could not be found from `C:\Users\windows\xxx\app\App.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

- `C:\Users\windows\xxx\app\screens\maps\mapbox(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json)`
- `C:\Users\windows\xxx\app\screens\maps\mapbox\index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json)`

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets'.

  > Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1